# Is there any way to split a string when is see Uppercase followed by a lowercase without spaces between them?

Tags: c#, .net, split

I have this string:

```
string countries = "SpainUnited StatesItalyFrance";
```

I need to separate the countries. The way I can think of is to separate the word when it finds a capital letter followed by a lowercase letter.

Comment: not inbuilt, but it seems like a pretty trivial regex split

Comment: How did you get the mess?  Instead of trying to patch the bad results, fix the root cause of the issue.

Comment: If I don't find anything else, I would create a list of all possible country values and use that to separate the values from string. Would that be simple?

Comment: Can you let us know the result you would expect from the string you have shown - specifically would you expect "United States" as one country - if so, then you cannot split on Upper/Lowercase sequence.

Comment: Have a look at my edited answer which preserves spaces in country names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a character for splitting using `Regex.Replace()` and then split by  it:

```
    string countries = "SpainUnited StatesItalyFrance";
    string[] result =  Regex.Replace(countries, "(\\S)([A-Z][a-z])", "$1_$2")
    .Split(new char[] { '_' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

[Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KRIV70)

Comment: you probably want to use `[a-z][A-Z]` to find when it *becomes* capitalized? and there is a `Regex.Split` that would seem more direct?

Comment: This splits 'United States' into 'United' and 'States' which is probably not wanted.

Comment: @HansKilian indeed - should probably be using `'\0'` in the split, not `' '`

Comment: Have a look at my edited answer which preserves spaces in country names.